# malicious packets originating from server IP address

Tags: security, ubuntu, networking

I am using Ubuntu-x86_64 x86_64 x86_64, and I am facing a lot of problem-related to server security and malicious activity on this server.

I had taken every possible step of server hardening to server security( like having the strong root password, proper permissions on all folders, disabling ssh, installing fail2ban, having proper `iptables` rule etc.). But still, the malicious attacks are not getting stopped.

Lately, I have found that my server has been greylisted. Below are the logs provided by a third party after third party intrusion.

==

```
The Defense Network captured malicious packets originating from this IP address. 
{
    "PORT HIT": "217.174.240.230:52006->217.#.#.160:8080",
    "MESSAGES": "Array
        (
            [06:58:03] => GET / HTTP/1.0
        User-Agent: muhstik/1.0 


        )
        "
}
```

I am not sure whether this is related to server or network. I don't know what my next step should be to tackle the situation. Any leads that can help me in curing the server of malicious attack?

Comment: Is that packet going from or to you? (is 217.174.240.130 your ip?)

Comment: yes, its my IP, packets are originating from this IP

Answer (score 0):

If the traffic originates from your server, you've already been compromised. It doesn't matter what protection you enable after the fact - you need to either remove the malicious software, or (even better) rebuild the server from scratch.

There's a good canonical answer for response to a compromise: https://serverfault.com/a/218011/11509

Also without knowing what services you're running on the server, we can't really recommend anything specific. But you can look at some usual resources - every bigger piece of software should have some kind of security guide available. For example if you're running wordpress, it would be https://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress - just google "software_name security guide". Since you're running some version of Ubuntu, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Security applies.